# Is it possible to send only one request to fetch more than One external javascript files?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am working on a webpage ,on which I need to fetch around 10 external .js files.So browser makes 10 requests to fetch them. Is there any way which I can bring all of them in one shot??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - if browser gets all 10 JS files, they will be stored in cache, so next request will load files from cache.

About merging files into one - you can create some script which will fetch all 10 files, merge their content and save in a specified file. Or do it by your own if JS files are static.

Comment: but still if I write a script to fetch and compress them all in to one,at some point of time it will have to make 10 requests. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Just one time during merging. You output merged file to the users so they make only one request. The best solution is to compress it as @Yari Nevet pointed.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I come bring all of them in One shot??

No, but you can bundle and compress them all into one single `JS` file.

That *would* save you the total round-trips time consumption for the all 10 files.

You can use online tools to achieve it easily, like:
http://jscompress.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try these

- compress and minify your javascript files
- Import all js files into one manually and do compress

Comments and whitespace are not needed for javascript execution; 
Removing them will speed up script execution times

OR

If possible, you can execute the script asynchronously. HTML5 has got this feature.
`<script>` tag has got [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) boolean property. make use of it.